# Gulp Save Issue

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

Been using gulp for ages, mainly for managing my sass files. Up until today everything has been working fine, until just recently tasks are running but their output is not being saved / written.

I have a scss file being watched, and should it be changed it is ran through gulp-ruby-sass (same issue even with gulp-sass) then spat back out in the specified directory, however this isn't happening. I get a notification letting me know it ran, however nothing is outputted, and for some strange reason if a switch from my PHPStorm window to iTerm they magically appear.

Anyone else experienced this? I'm literally tearing my hair out right now cause I can't figure out what's wrong.

Cheers.

Comment: Can you include your gulpfile into the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it all out. Didn't realise that Gulp doesn't run tasks synchronously, or at least not in the order you might want them to run - apparently sometimes they even run in parallel with each other. Anyway, you can tell a task to wait by adding an array as a second item when you call the tasks function. In this array add the names of any tasks that must run before this one can start.

Took a little bit of digging for me to find, so not sure if this is widely known or I've managed to completely miss this somehow, but hope it might help someone else in the future!